# creating popup content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say i have this code

```
<p id="test">
  some content
<p>
<a href="#" id="test-link">Open</a>
```

Now i want -using javascript/jquery- to create a popup window, the window content is the content of `test` paragraph, when `test-link` is clicked.
How could this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  <a href="javascript:popup();"  id="test-link">Open</a>

function popup()
{
  var generator=window.open('','name','height=400,width=500');

  generator.document.write('<html><head><title>Popup</title>');
  generator.document.write($("#test").html());
  generator.document.write('</body></html>');
  generator.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [jQuery UI (dialog)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) (see examples in the reference documentation).

Comment: Unfortunately, I want a popup window, not a modal or dialog.

Comment: In this case, the answer by pranay_stacker should work.

I tend to prefer dialogs, since they you can get more control regarding their position and they tend to look better. Some people force popups to open in new tabs and/or prevent them from resizing, since these can be annoying depending on the site, especially auto-opening (onload) popups, although few modern websites seem to use those nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

im using http://defunkt.github.com/facebox/ its nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)** to show popup.

For your html:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#test-link").click(function()
    {
         $("#test").dialog({ resizable: true,
                modal: false, draggable: true
         });
    });
});
```

If you don't want to go for jQuery UI dialog then you can use **[ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)**.