# Display popup for users

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a popup as shown on Google maps, to rate restaurants (after search). The user hovers over the overall rating, and then a popup is shown on which user can rate. I am using jquery. The popup should disappear once focus is lost from the popup. So, basically I want to know how to display such a popup ?

Comment: a quick google search for ["jquery tooltip"](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=jquery%20tool%20tip) or ["jquery modal window"](http://www.google.com/#pq=jquery+tool+tip&hl=en&sugexp=pfwc&cp=14&gs_id=51&xhr=t&q=jquery+modal+window) will lead you to boat-loads of good tools. There will *literally* be large boats full of different answers.

Comment: @MichaelJasper So true.  Its interesting too that people are starting to come to SO first before google; not many sites can boast that!

Comment: @chown - The problem is they aren't searching SO, they are just asking questions that have been answered before. I don't think it deserves a down vote though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117879/creating-popup-content-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jquery tooltip is a good one](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html)

Its as simple as:

```
$("[title]").tooltip();
// or
// $(".trigger").tooltip({ position: "bottom left", opacity: 0.7});
```

---

Even customize the html inside the tooltip (from their example [page here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html)):

```
<!-- trigger element. a regular workable link -->
<a id="download_now">Download now</a>

<!-- tooltip element -->
<div class="tooltip">

    <img src="http://static.flowplayer.org/img/title/eye.png" alt="Flying screens" 
        style="float:left;margin:0 15px 20px 0" />

    <table style="margin:0">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">File</td>
            <td>flowplayer-3.2.7.zip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Date</td>
            <td>2011-03-03</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Size</td>
            <td>112 kB</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">OS</td>
            <td>all</td>
        </tr>       
    </table>

    <a href="/3.2/">What's new in 3.2</a>
</div>
```

Then:

```
$("#download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
```